# Loading premade .xnb files with content manger

Tags: xna

I am trying to load premade .xnb files with the content pipeline.
when I call `contentManager.Load<model>("grass");`, for which I have a "grass.xnb" file in the corresponding directory, it crashes with: "Error loading "grass_0". File not found."

The grass.xnb file was created using a MSBuild wrapper to build the .fbx files.
I initialized the content manager with : 
`contentManager = new ContentManager(mainXnaWindow.Services, projectFileOpen + "../Assets/XNB/"));`
I am pretty sure the content manager has the right directory, because when I deleted "grass.xnb" from the directory, It just told me "Error loading "grass" File not found"

Does anyone know why it could be adding a "_0" to the name?

Edit: I forgot to include a built version of th texture associated with it. Problem Solved.

Comment: You need to say something about this `grass_0` file. It's the thing causing the error so we need to know about it (currently we know nothing). We also need to know what it has to do with `myModel.xnb`, unless that was just a roundabout way of saying you call `contentManager.Load<model>("grass");`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've cleared up and added some details.

Comment: maybe grass_0 is it's texture and it needs it to completly load model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .xnb file wouldn't load because it was looking for another .xnb file, the texture to go with the model.

I fixed this by making sure that all of the built .xnb files were in the directory I was loading from.